# Align button centrally below horizontal form layout with bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following layout and here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/raxuji/edit?html,output) of the layout

```
<div class="container-fluid" >    
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
      <label><strong>Field One</strong></label>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1">
      <div class="invisible hidden-xs" style="padding-top: 11px">
        &nbsp;
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <strong>OR</strong>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <label><strong>Other Field</strong></label>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Button</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When in non mobile mode, I want the inputs to take up as much space as possible with the or Label positioned in between the inputs.

I then need the button centred but I am having difficulties because I want the inputs to be col-sm-5 and col-sm-6 but as this is an odd number of columns it is difficult to get the button centered.

Answer (score 0):

To align your button the same as the form, add an offset of 5 to it. Add class `col-md-offset-5` and make the button `col-md-1`. Let the `col-sm` classes as they are. This will always align the button below the 'OR' in your form. Hope that helps.